# Why am I not able to remove first node from the linked list with this code?

Tags: java, linked-list

Below is my method that shows how I am trying to delete a node from linked list. Added complete implementation, including the node and how I am creating the linkedlist.

```
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    Node(int n){
        this.val = n;
    }
}
Public class LinkedList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inp = {100,3,1,50,25};
        Node head = createLinkedList(inp);
        displayList(head);
        System.out.println("List after the node is removed:");
        removeNode(head,100);
        displayList(head);
}

static void removeNode(Node head, int val) {
        Node sentinal = new Node(-1);
        sentinal.next = head;
        Node prev = sentinal;
        while(head!=null){
            if(head.val==val){
                prev.next = head.next;
                return;
            }
            prev=head;
            head=head.next;
        }
    }

static Node createLinkedList(int[] inp){
        Node head = new Node(-1);
        Node temp = head;
        for(int n:inp){
            temp.next = new Node(n);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return head.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the first node? then why not do it this way. 
I don't know your code structor but this can help you:

```java
public void RemoveFirst() {
        this.Head = Head.Next();
        this.Size -= 1;
    }
```

always remember to keep track of the size of the list

Comment: I updated my code to show how I am creating the linkedlist and the Node structure as well.